# Inequality of elementary symmetric polynomials

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials

Let $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4)$ with $\lambda_i>0$ for $i=1,2,3,4$. Let $$\sigma_k(\lambda)=\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2\cdots<i_k\leq4}\lambda_{i_1}\lambda_{i_2}\cdots\lambda_{i_k},\quad k=1,2,3,4$$ be the elementary symmetric polynomials. Prove the following inequality $$\sigma_2^2-3\sigma_1\sigma_3+12\sigma_4\geq0.$$ Furthermore, characterize the equality case.

To deal with inequalities of symmetric polynomials, Newton Maclaurin type inequalities also be useful. I tried to use the following inequlities $$\sigma_1/4\geq\frac{\sigma_2/6}{\sigma_1/4}\geq\frac{\sigma_3/4}{\sigma_2/6}\geq\frac{\sigma_4}{\sigma_3/4},$$ but failed.

Comment: What exactly is the positive cone of $\mathbb R^4$ ? Or of $\mathbb R^3,$ for that matter ? And is $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4)$ ? Or are you asking us to add and multiply [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) ?

Comment: There is no $k$ in your definition of $\sigma_k$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This method works often with symmetric inequalities. Assume an order
$$0 \le \lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 \le \lambda_3 \le \lambda_4$$ and write
$$\lambda_k = l_1 +\ldots + l_k$$ where $l_i$ are all $\ge 0$. Substitute in your inequality and see what you get.  You will also notice that the equality is achieved if an only if at least three of the $\lambda_i$'s  are equal.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity of presentation, let
$$E_k(\lambda)=\binom{4}{k}^{-1}\sigma_k(\lambda),\quad 1\le k\le 4,$$
be the normalized elementary symmetric polynomials.

From Newton-Maclaurin inequalities, we get
$$E_1 E_3\le E_2^2\le E_4.$$

Hence
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{12}[\sigma_2^2-3\sigma_1\sigma_3+12\sigma_4]
&=3E_2^2-4E_1 E_3+E_4 \\
&\ge 3E_2^2-4E_2^2+E_4=E_4-E_2^2\\
&\ge0,
\end{align*}
with the equality holds if and only if $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=\lambda_4.$